Crop PDF then Read Text from PDF
I am trying to avoid reading 'page ... of ...' on a pdf as it messes up with the other data being read.
I thought it would be easiest to just crop the margins out and then read the pdf.
I tried using Fitz and PyPDF2.
After saving the files, the PDF appeared cropped. However, when using pdfplumber or PyPDF2 to read text, it seems like it is reading it from the original PDF.
Is there any way to crop a PDF and read text from the cropped PDF?

Is this a programming-related question? If so, then please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Cropping a PDF normally only means setting the CropBox of the page, the visible section of the endless page canvas. Text extractors on the other hand often ignore this box by default and extract all text content on a page. Often there is some option on text extractors to restrict to the crop box.

The question needs additional details to reproduce the problem. For example, pdfplumber 0.11.4 extracts only the text within the cropped area, which remains part of the original document. Yes, it reads the text from the original document, but only within the limits of a bounding box. So, what's the problem?
